# Can Prototypical OOP Be Considered a Paradigm In C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, prototype, paradigms

Good day,

considering the following code, could one classify prototypical OOP to be a paradigm in

C++?

```
#include <iostream>

template< class... Bases >
struct TestClass : public Bases...
{
    int a;
    template< class... Parents >
    TestClass< Parents... >* Create() {
        return new TestClass< Parents... >();
    }
    TestClass< Bases... >* Create() {
        return new TestClass< Bases... >();
    }
};
struct Foo {
    int fizz;
};
struct Bar {
    int buzz;
};
int main()
{
    TestClass< Foo > a;
    a.a = 10;
    a.fizz = 20;
    std::cerr << a.fizz << "\n";
    std::cerr << a.a << "\n";
    auto b = a.Create();
    b->fizz = 30;
    std::cerr << b->fizz << "\n";
    auto c = b->Create< Bar >();
    c->buzz = 357;
    std::cerr << c->buzz << "\n";
    auto d = b->Create< Foo, Bar >();
    d->fizz = 0;
    d->buzz = 1;
    std::cerr << d->fizz << "\n";
    std::cerr << d->buzz << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

FYI, I forgot to manage my memory, sorry!

Comment: Nitpicker's corner: it's usually rendered as "prototypal" (vs "prototypical").

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain: He means for you to edit your post and change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think so. The key difference between "prototypical" and "classical" OO is that prototypical OO doesn't have classes: the prototype is itself an object. If the prototype is modified, all objects "inheriting" from it follow suit. In this example, that is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help but notice a lot of confusion.

1. The member function template 'Create' doesn't actually

   - have anything to with a TestClass instance (should be static)
   - have anything to with the containing TestClass's *template arguments* (should be a namespace function, not a member of the class template)
2. the non-generic `Create` method should use the 'injected' type name instead of spelling the template args out needlessly
3. there is no polymorphic use, so don't unnecessary dynamic allocations or raw pointers (this also solves the problem with memory cleanup)
4. minor nit: *try to use less confusing names and formatting in examples*

Here's my equivalent:

```
template< class... Bases >
struct TestClass : public Bases... {
    int testfield;
    TestClass Create() {
        return TestClass();
    }
};

template< class... Parents >
static TestClass< Parents... > CreateTestClass() {
    return TestClass<Parents... >();
}

struct Fizzer {
    int fizz;
};
struct Buzzer {
    int buzz;
};
int main()
{
    TestClass< Fizzer > fizzer;
    fizzer.testfield = 10;
    fizzer.fizz = 20;

    auto b = fizzer.Create();
    b.fizz = 30;

    auto c = CreateTestClass< Buzzer >();
    c.buzz = 357;

    auto d = CreateTestClass< Fizzer, Buzzer >();
    d.fizz = 0;
    d.buzz = 1;
}
```

And, NO, I don't think this code is 'idiomatic' for much. I haven't seen it (although it might resemble a straightforward implementation of a tuple-like class. That's not idiomatic, anyway: idiomatic would be to **not** write such a class, but to compose std::tuple (boost has several flavours with extensions)

Comment: Thank you for the advice you bring up some good points, although I was writing this on an iPad. :-P

Comment: All the more reason to stay away from funny characters like `*` and `<>` and reduce typing in general :) Cheers